# mask part of a string using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I would like to mask part of a string.For eg:

```
https://example.com/test?abc=12345678901234567890123456&mnr=12345678901234567890123456
```

to

```
https://example.com/test?abc=********************123456&mnr=12345678901234567890123456
```

I need to mask first 20 digits after `"abc="` and keep last 6 digits as it is.

I tried `(?<=abc=)(.*?)(?=&mnr)` but it is showing `example.com/test?abc=*&mnr=12345678901234567890123456`

what will be the regular expression if abc= contains characters as well as numbers

Comment: Can you please clarify/narrow down the logic for which part of the URL gets masked?  Also, include any code if you have it to share with us.

Comment: I need to mask first 20 digits after "abc=" and keep last 6 digits  as it is.I tried   (?<=abc=)(.*?)(?=&mnr) but it is showing  https://example.com/test?abc=*&mnr=12345678901234567890123456

Comment: Show your code in the question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regular will find the first 14 digit characters of abc paramter in the url:

```
(?<=abc=)[0-9]{14}(?=[0-9]{6})
```

Replacing:

```
String data = "https://example.com/test?abc=12345678901234567890123456&mnr=12345678901234567890123456";

String result = data.replaceAll("(?<=abc=)[0-9]{14}(?=[0-9]{6})",
            "**************");

System.out.println(result);
```

Result:

```
https://example.com/test?abc=**************567890123456&mnr=12345678901234567890123456
```

For more beautiful solution you can use this regex:

```
(?<=abc=[0-9]{0,14})[0-9](?=[0-9]{6})
```

And replacing will be:

```
String data = "https://example.com/test?abc=12345678901234567890123456&mnr=12345678901234567890123456";

String result = data.replaceAll("(?<=abc=[0-9]{0,14})[0-9](?=[0-9]{6})", "*");

System.out.println(result);
```

Result:

```
https://example.com/test?abc=***************67890123456&mnr=12345678901234567890123456
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
abc=\d{20}
```

and replace by this:

```
abc=********************
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DPefGn/2)

But if you want to validate if abc= followed by 20 digits and then 6 digits and then &mnr and then want to replace the first 20 digits of abc then you may use this regex:

```
abc=\d{20}(?=\d{6}&mnr)
```

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/DPefGn/3)

if abc is followed by anything other than digit and you also want to address that, then you may try this:

replace `\d{20}` by `\.{20}`

Comment: what will be the regular expression if abc= contains characters as well as numbers?

Comment: @Sarika. `.{20}` should be fine